# Whether amino acids exist as zwitterions in the liquid and gaseous phases

Tags: organic-chemistry, carbonyl-compounds

I am aware that in the solid state **pure** amino acids are crystalline structures composed of zwitterions, however I cannot find any information about whether somehow this changes as they move into liquid and gaseous forms- are they zwitterions in these sates and if not, why not?

Comment: There's always equilibrium there - more or less of both forms.